# Rancher monitoring is not working, KubeAPI is down

Tags: azure, kubernetes, prometheus, azure-aks, rancher

I am trying to enable the Monitoring through Rancher. All the pods are running fine, but when I see the logs, I can see that `KubeAPI has disappeared from Prometheus target discovery`
[image]

[image]

Also, the serviceMonitor of the default namespace of the Prometheus is fetching the external IP and hence that also is failing. Have anyone came across this issue? Any help would be appreciated.